# Increase Thread Wait Times in Parallel.Foreach Loop

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify the thread wait times in Parallel.Foreach Library?

Comment: What is `thread wait times` ?

Comment: For example if i want to specify that a cetain thread to wait for 5 seconds max if it is blocked by the preceeding thread.

Comment: Can you show us how you're waiting? did you mean that you're using `Thread.Sleep`?

Answer (score 1):

You can lock using a `Monitor` and specify its timeout:

```
// early in the method.
var obj = new object();

int timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds
bool lockWasTaken;

try
{
    lockWasTaken = Monitor.TryEnter(obj, timeout);
    if (lockwasTaken);
    {
        // your critical code
    }
}
finally
{
    if (lockWasTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. If the local object is created *before* `Parallel.ForEach` is called, it's a perfectly useful locking object.